# Why does textAlign in Openlayers look opposite?

Tags: openlayers, labeling, alignment

As far as I know with CSS knowledge, `textAlign:left` means the text should be stick left of the element. [W3School textalign](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_text-align)

but in Openlayers, it looks working opposite.
[Openlayers vector label example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-labels.html).
click the link above, and choose `left` from `align` select box, then press `refresh` then the texts moves to right side like `textAlign:right`.

How does `textAlign` work in OpenLayers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it is not opposite. `TextAlign`works relative to something.  In the case of the W3Schools example, in the case of left-align, it aligns the left hand end of the text (its start) to the left-hand side of the page.  For right-align, it aligns the right-hand side of the text (its end) to the right hand side of the page.

With OL, the text is being aligned to a point location and not a page.  So left align aligns the left-hand-end of the text string (ie the start) to the point (or centroid), which is why it sticks out to the right of the point.  This is why, with a point location the `start` and `end` alignment options effectively work the same as `left` and `right` respectively.

Comment: Thanks! very clear. so is not the same concept as css `textAlign`. for `start` and `end` is reasonable but it feels they should swap for `left` and `right`